# Why is remember-me a lesser authentication then full-authentication in spring-security?

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-session, spring-security-rest

This is a conceptual question about the fact, that authentication has different grades in spring security.

There is a grade for

1. [anonymous authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#anonymous) also called `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`
2. and [remember me authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-rememberme) `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED`
3. the full authentication, when a user just provided his entire credentials and got confirmed aka `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY`

In the implementation of `AuthenticatedVoter#isFullyAuthenticated` it is clear, that a full authenticated user cannot be `anonymous authenticated` or `remember-me authenticated`.

While I fully understand why we differentiate between `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` and `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`, I really do not understand why `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED` is not treated equally to `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY`.

## How I understand remember me:

I understand remember me as authentication using some kind of secret token - using this token we load an existing `SecurityContext` which already includes the fully authenticated `Authentication` object written there during the initial `full authentication`. It is basically restored full authentication in this regard.

Comparing this to the session-login, which has a similar token but considered full-authentication in spring security, why is there a difference between remember-me and session-based?

## Question:

Considering that remember-me restored a full-authenticated `SecurityContext`, the application logic would treat the context the same as it would be just normal full authentication.

If we would have some logic for full authenticated users in the application, it would surely also apply to remeber-me authenticated cases.

Of course, for `anonymous authenticated` users we often have different decisions to take, so that is why I understand why this is singled out.

Do I understand the concept of remember-me the wrong way or what is the exact reason not counting users `remembered` as fully authenticated?

Comment: With "remember me" you'd run risk that someone else accesses the application without the need to provide credentials and that happening without the original user's consent or knowledge. Hence this should be considered a lower level of authentication: you know the user logged in successfully at some point but you don't know the one returning to the session still is that user.

Comment: Stealing a session this way is as hard as stealing a password (mostly). We are required to somehow get a secret, the session token, and provide this to get authentication. It is like a PAT, isn't it? Having session-based authentication will be one of the usual things in spring boot. I could not imagine how the actual backend logic would differ internally between those 2 (full/remember me)  when looking at the security context. Is this flagging just something that is to be known about in the spring-secuirty filter chain (and acted upon) - but then those 2 are the same ( same SecurityContext)?

Comment: It probably depends on your view but remembering and thus restoring a session with some time of inactivity in between runs the risk of the users being different people. It's not about stealing the session but someone else accessing the users computer. You could argue that the OS session should be locked as well but you as an application provider can't and shouldn't rely on that being the case. If you really want to treat a remembered session the same as a fully authenticated one you should still be able to do so but it would be your choice and responsibility.

Comment: Also note that applications often require an already authenticated user to re-authenticate for critical operations for the same reason: even with the session still being active there's no guarantee that the person in front of a machine still is the one that logged in or if that person went away and forgot to lock their screen.

Comment: The access of a computer from someone else could also abuse username/password scenarios, would it? Or are you pointing on the fact that session-id is purely by property and username/password(when not written down on the computer) is by knowledge and thus the latter is considered save? If I would differ those, I would mean to know longer allow session based logins at all, or as you posted, have some kind of re-authentication/validation of the user 'after some time' (30 minutes). Are you differing remember me from session here? Means, the session has an expiry (and a token), is the remember me..

Comment: .. token a different token (cookie most probably) and so you treat them differently? So lets assume, session expires after 30 minutes, remember me after 3days. This would mean that 30m the user is fully authenticated, but when no req. is done for 30m, the session expires and then remember-me kicks in, maybe needs re-validation. So 2 tokens with different lifetimes and different treatment (session is full-authed, remember me needs upgrade)?

Comment: Basically yes. Note that there is no "this is considered safe" but a more generic "this can be considered to be more or less safe than something else". Assuming the users don't share their credentials and always lock their machines when they aren't using them you _could_ consider "remember me" and full authentication to be equally safe. But you'd base your considerations on assumptions or solutions external to the application which you might not be able to control.

Comment: I understand, so it is to be said, that remember me is considered to be riskier then full-authentication. In addition, session-based login is considered less risky then remember me due to the shorter lifetime. That said, how do you treat session based SecurityContext 'restoration' - from my POV those are treated 'full authenticated' in spring security, right?

Comment: @Thomas i slighly adjusted my question (the 'how I  understand remember me part') so the question is easier to answer. Feel free to do so so I can accept your answer, which really was very helpful in the comments already!

Comment: I'll try to collect it into an answer but I can't provide any specifics on Spring Security since I didn't use it myself that much yet (mostly worked on other frameworks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Comparing this to the session-login, which has a similar token but considered full-authentication in spring security, why is there a difference between remember-me and session-based?

Normally you have a lower session timeout than the life span of a remember-me token. According to Spring's documentation the remember-me token has a life span of 2 weeks as opposed to the session timeout often just defined in minutes.

Remember-me could be thought of being similar to restoring a session that timed out but that would be as insecure as just restoring the security context. Why?

In general you want to apply several security layers and there are some you as an application developer would not of control of (at least not directly), e.g.:

- There is no guarantee that users don't share their credentials (uersname/password) so multi-factor authentication might be required.
- There is no guarantee that an authenticated user steps away from their machine and don't lock it. In that case someone else could access the application and thus you would want to keep tokens as short-lived as possible. Many applications thus use additional tokens for critical operations, e.g. when I can put products into my cart on Amazon but when I want to place the order I'm required to re-authenticate to make sure it's actually me.

It's basically the second risk that remember-me increases: You only can assume a user is still in front of their machine if they are actively using the application so you'd want to make your session timeouts as short as possible to quickly determine a user is inactive (and long-lived enough to maintain a good level of usability).

Remember-me would reactivate an inactive session (or at least the associated security context) and thus here you *assume* that the user now in front of the machine is the original one. There's no guarantee of that and hence remember-me authentication can be considered less secure.

OAuth refresh tokens could be considered something similar: you get an access token when the user is successfully authenticated but access token would expire regardless of activity. Then you'd use a refresh token to get a new access token if the session is still active (which doesn't guarantee the user is or didn't change).

So in terms of security and not considering authentication options I'd rank them in the following order:

- [access token](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-1.4) retrieved by authenticating the user explicitly: use this for critical operations, make them short-lived and don't provide refresh tokens for those
- [refresh token](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-1.5) and access tokens retrieved via a refresh token: basically comparable to session security as refresh tokens life spans often are related to session life spans (if a user doesn't access a protected resource within time X then both the access and refresh tokens would have expired and the user would need to re-authenticate). Note that refresh tokens should not be shared with the user.
- remember-me tokens: could be considered a form of long-lived refresh token that is shared with the user